# Plotting a normal curve over a histogram

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics

I am teaching a basic introduction to normal curves, and the textbook introduces the topic with the idea of rolling five dice and recording the sum.   Do this many times and create a histogram of the results.  (which looks more and more like the normal curve as the number of trials increases)   My "code" to simulate this for 10000 rolls is below.

```
rolls = Table[Table[RandomChoice[Range[6]], {5}], {10000}];
sums = Total /@ rolls;
Histogram[sums, {0.5, 31.5, 1}]
```

I am way out of my depth here, but wondered if anyone could help with how to plot the "perfect" normal curve that would match the histogram?

I have the following to plot a normal curve, but for it to match the dice example, I need the mean and standard deviation, and how no idea what that would be.

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -3, 3}, Ticks -> None, 
 Axes -> None]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your definitions of `rolls` and `sums`, you can find the parameters for the corresponding normal distribution by calculating the mean and standard deviation of `sums` directly, using `Mean` and `StandardDeviation`, or more generally using [`FindDistributionParameters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html):

```
pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma] /. 
   FindDistributionParameters[sums, NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]]]
```

With those in hand, you can plot the histogram and the PDF of the calculated distribution. Here I shown them both scaled as PDFs:

```
Show[
 Plot[pdf[x], {x, 0, 35}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red]],
 Histogram[sums, {0.5, 31.5, 1}, "PDF"]
]
```

[image: combined histogram and pdf]

Alternatively if you want it expressed in counts, you have to account for the total number of rolls:

```
Show[
 Plot[10000 pdf[x], {x, 0, 35}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red]],
 Histogram[sums, {0.5, 31.5, 1}]
]
```

[image: overlay of histogram and PDF scaled for counts]

---

Incidentally, I would recommend calculating `rolls` in one go as follows, rather than with nested tables:

```
rolls = RandomChoice[Range[6], {10000, 5}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to take advantage of some of the built-in probability stuff.  I couldn't find or remember what distribution does the sum of dice.  `TransformedDistribution` didn't work (or I made an error).  Note: For the normal distribution, we use the theoretical mean and standard deviation instead of empirical estimates of them based on sample sum.

```
dicedist = DiscreteUniformDistribution[Table[{1, 6}, {5}]];

(* roll the dice *)
RandomVariate[dicedist]
(*  {1, 6, 4, 6, 5}  *)

mu = Total@Mean[dicedist];
sd = Sqrt@Total@Variance[dicedist];

Show[
 Histogram[Total /@ RandomVariate[dicedist, 2000], Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sd], x], {x, 5, 30}]
 ]
```

[image]

An interactive demonstration:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Histogram[Total /@ RandomVariate[dicedist, n], Automatic, "PDF"],
  Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sd], x], {x, 5, 30}],
  PlotRange -> {{4.5, 30.5}, {-0.01, 
     1.5 PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sd], mu]}},
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> HoldForm["n" == #] &@n, Axes -> False
  ],
 {n, 20, 10000, 10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rolls = Table[Table[RandomChoice[Range[6]], {5}], {10000}];
sums = Total /@ rolls;
fig1 = Histogram[sums, {0.5, 31.5, 1}, "PDF"];
mean = Mean@sums;
std = StandardDeviation@sums;
fig2 = Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mean, std], x], {x, 0, 30}, 
   Ticks -> None, Axes -> None];
Show[{fig1 , fig2}]
```

[image]

If you wanna use count, then

```
rolls = Table[Table[RandomChoice[Range[6]], {5}], {10000}];
sums = Total /@ rolls;
fig1 = Histogram[sums, {0.5, 31.5, 1}];
mean = Mean@sums;
std = StandardDeviation@sums;
fig2 = Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mean, std], x], {x, 0, 30}, 
   Ticks -> None, Axes -> None];
Overlay[{fig1 , fig2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why does the normal curve look like it results in negative values in the tail regions?

Comment: @JimB I think the `ImagePadding` needs to be specified (and the same) for both plots in order to use `Overlay`.

Comment: @MassDefect: That makes sense (and I assume that's in part because of the `Axes->None` option in `fig2`).  Maybe using `10000 PDF[NormalDistribution[mean, std], x]` in `fig2` and `Show[fig1,fig2]` would be better.